# Mockito's inOrder() and sets/maps

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following situation: My class keeps two identity sets of objects.

The sets are gradually filled with some instances, in the test case they are filled with mocks.

Then my class has a call that does something with the contents of one set, then with the contents of the other. That is the call I am testing.

The order in which the sets are processed is important. The order in which the individual objecst are processed within sets is not important, and in fact it varies depending on how identity hash is assigned to the mocks in the sets.

So in my situation I have a partial order: all of these objects must be processed before any of those objects.

The question is, how can I express it in Mockito? inOrder() breaks down because I have to specify the exact order of objects, and that is not constant.

Comment: Why don't you mock your sets? This is what you really want to test.

Comment: @Ezequiel I think I see your point here - wrap sets into their own objects, so my class' functionality consists of just directing the incoming mock to the right place and then calling the "iterate" method on those places in the right order. Hmmm. That may work. Thanks for the idea. Could you re-post it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

To discuss how to deal with collections and maps when using Mockito.inOrder, we have to distinguish 4 situations depending on

- whether the collection or map is input or is created inside the method (input means it is accessed via a method parameter, a class variable or returned by method call that can be stubbed)
- whether the collection or map is accessed or iterated inside the method (or another method from the same class or a super class that is called and because of that can't be stubbed)

That results in 4 combinations or 4 possible situations.

1. The collection or map is an input parameter of the method being tested and the method passes it to another method or returns it but doesn't touch it.
   In that case just mock the collection or map. There is no problem.
2. The collection or map is an input parameter of the method being tested and the method accesses (or iterates) it.
   In that case, you create a collection or set containing one or more mocks. You should never mock the collection or map itself in this case, because you can't know which methods are called and need to be stubbed when iterating it using a for loop or a stream (it depends on the implementation of the JRE!).
   Because you have to create it yourself before calling the method, you can decide what implementation you will use. If it contains 2 or more mocked objects or the method being tested adds objects to it, then create an ordered collection or map.
   And if the method should not modify it, but only read it, then create a non modifiable collection or map. I like to use Collections.singleton, Collections.singletonList and Arrays.asList in tests.
3. The method being tested creates and fills the collection, but doesn't access or iterate it.
   If the method adds objects to the set or map, which are passed in as parameters and then passes the set or map to another map or returns it, there is no problem.
   In that case there are no calls to verify that depend on an iteration order. You just need to assert it's content afterwards (when returned or using a captor if not returned but passed to another method).
4. The method being tested creates and fills the collection and accesses or iterates it.
   When the method creates the collection or map and adds mocks into it and then iterates it and acts on those mocks, then there is indeed a problem if you are using inOrder and the collection or map isn't ordered.
   In that case, you should try to split up the method into 2 methods: one method that creates and fills the collection or map (ending up in situation 3, it can be a factory method in a factory class) and a second method that accesses or iterates it (ending up situation 2). Just creating a factory method and calling it from the already existing method can be enough to solve the problem.

When the class containing the method being tested has a set or map as a class variable, you can consider it as an input for the method if the method accesses or modifies it and as an output if the method sets it.
But if it is a private or protected class variable which doesn't have a setter or getter, you might need to use reflection to set it with a mock or with a set or map containing one or more mocks before calling your method or to get and verify it after calling your method.